# .TTF Invalid Font on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, truetype

I am having an issue with installing a font on a user's computer where I receive an error message that states that the specific font is invalid. I cannot replicate this issue on my computer or other user's computers where I have successfully installed the font.

The font is called "Code39AzaleaNarrow2.ttf" and is a TrueType font file. I have tried several things:

- Making sure that the user has the required permissions to write to the font folder.
- Storing the font file on the local computer and not only accessible through a shared drive.
- Making sure the user is an administrator on the computer.

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to install this specific font. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is there a reason this question is getting downvoted? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was local administrator rights. I thought the user had the necessary rights but I missed one.